I've got an error that reads: Error occurred during initialization of boot layer in Intellij using javaFX
I have tried everithing this is the complete error that i am getting:
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found
This is my project structure:
Project structure libraries and classes.
Modules
libraries
run/debug configurations
this is the preview in scenebuilder:
scenebuilder
Can any of you guys help me? We can even do a call, lol because I have been stuck in this problem for a long time now and I don't know how to fix it. I tried watching videos, but I made no progress. Please let me know if you need more information to solve this issue. Thank you.

Post text, not images, wherever practical.

Post the contents of your module-info.java file. Are you aware of Java Platform Module System?

Your run/debug configuration seems to have a path trying to point into a ZIP file, which seems odd. But ignoring that, you are using Maven and so you should be relying on Maven to manage dependencies instead of IntelliJ. To make things easier, declare JavaFX as dependencies in your POM and forget about using an external JavaFX SDK (at least for now). You should also be relying on Maven to run your application in your development environment. This is simplified by applying the javafx-maven-plugin plugin, configuring it, and executing the javafx:run goal.

Try following the instructions under JavaFX and IntelliJ, specifically one of the "with Maven" sections, over at Getting Started with JavaFX. Once you get a simple project running, then you can start adding your own code.

You are using IntelliJ, yes? If so, create your project using its JavaFX template. See the manual.
